# can we able to automate ESRI windows application map

Tags: automation, hp-uft, testcomplete, uipath

i am trying to automate a windows/Desktop application which has ESRI Map operation functionalities. I tried with Unified Functional Testing version 14.03  (UFT) and TestComplete version 12.50 automation tools. 
 
When I try to identify any object inside map, I could not able to identify any object inside map. Because it identifies Map as a Image. So I am not able to do any operations (Like Click ,Get property values,Exists,Zoom in,Zoom out) in Map.
​
Please suggest us if any specific tool which supports ESRI Map operations

Answer (score 0):

Classical UI automation tools work with UI objects programmatically to perform actions against them. Maps and similar UI elements usually do not contain any standard objects and are drawn by a custom engine. This makes it very difficult to automate these actions.

The most viable way to automate UI of such applications is using OCR (optical character recognition), image-based search, gestures simulation and other similar approaches. In fact, TestComplete gives users all such advanced possibilities. You can [request assistance](http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete) from the vendor to get more details.